# convert NSData to NSString with encoding windows-1255

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser, nsdata

In my app,  I download **rss** file with **encoding="windows-1255".**
I read, that I need to convert it to UTF8 before passing it to `NSXMLParser`.

If that true, (any comments about that will help offcourse..)

I also have this code sample, but I dont see the const for 1255 encoding.

```
NSString *myStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:myData encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
```

How can i convert with `1255`, instead of `1252` ?

tnx

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible.

```
NSString* encoding = @"windows-1255";

CFStringEncoding cfEncoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((__bridge CFStringRef)encoding);
NSStringEncoding nsEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfEncoding);

NSString* decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:nsEncoding];
```

`CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding` converts the encoding name to a `CFStringEncoding` value, and `CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding` converts the `CFStringEncoding` to `NSStringEncoding` which you can use creating the `NSString` from `NSData`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no such encoding in SDK. However, you can write encoding by yourself - put unicode characters (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255, for instance) in array [0..255], and put the needed char in string instead of each byte in NSData.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go ahead and try to parse your file directly. Don't try to solve a problem if you haven't actually encountered it.

There are strong probabilities that your file will be parsed fine without any exotic conversion, especially if it's a standard RSS feed, no matter the version.